# Highchart bubble cut off with max x/yAxis

Tags: highcharts

I need to have a bubble chart with xAxis and yAxis from 0 to 5. If I have a bubble on the xAxis or yAxis 5, the bubble get cut of.

```
$(function () {
    $('#container').highcharts({

        chart: {
            type: 'bubble',
            zoomType: 'xy',
            height: 500,
            width: 500,
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Highcharts Bubbles'
        },
        yAxis: {
            min: 0, 
            max: 5,
            gridLineWidth: 1,
        },
        xAxis: {
            min: 0, 
            max: 5,
            gridLineWidth: 1,
        },
        series: [{
            data: [[5, 4, 2], [3, 1, 1], [4, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3], [1, 4, 1], [2, 5, 1], [5, 2, 3], [3, 2, 1]]
        }]
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/tum3zzzu/1/

I somehow found a trick with doing max: 5.5 but it work only for xAxis. On yAxis max: 5.5 is rounded to 6.

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: if I put endOnTick: false; and max: 5.5; it somehow make the job but it still not perfect because we see the gridline over 5. http://jsfiddle.net/tum3zzzu/2/

Comment: Instead of max, you can use [maxPadding](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#yAxis.maxPadding) then you avoid static values.

Comment: @SebastianBochan I need to use the max in order to display the axis until 5, even if no bubble has X or Y to 5.

Answer (score 2):

You can use **tickPositioner** to tell the chart exactly what to show as ticks. I also used **`showLastLabel: false`** to hide the last tick (which is 5.5). Here's what you can do in your code:

```
yAxis: {
    min: 0, 
    max: 5.5,
    endOnTick: true,
    showLastLabel: false,        // to hide 5.5
    gridLineWidth: 1,
    tickPositioner: function() {

        var positions = [0],     // to start from 0
            tick = Math.floor(this.dataMin),
            increment = Math.ceil((this.dataMax - this.dataMin) / 6);

        for (tick; tick - increment < this.dataMax; tick += increment) {
            positions.push(tick);
        }

        positions.push(this.dataMax + 0.5); // to add the last label 5.5

        return positions;
    }
}
```

And Here's the [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/tum3zzzu/8/).

Comment: +1 for the showLastLabel. But after I don't see the purpose of the rest of your code!! max: 5.5, and endOnTick: true is enough. But actually the best would be to have something like a padding and to have the axis really from 0 to 5.

Comment: Here's what it will look like if I remove the **`tickPositioner`** function: http://jsfiddle.net/tum3zzzu/9/  The yAxis goes to 6, the xAxis to 5.5, and the chart is not a square anymore, it's a rectangle.

Comment: @Alexandre didn't you want the edges to be there?

Comment: I would like to don't to see any line over x/yAxis 5 but to have the full bubble. Actually the best would be to keep max: 5 but to find a way to display the complete bubble.